# How to find empty cells in excel to hide the row

Tags: excel, vba

I try to find empty cells in my Worksheet and then hide the complete row. I can hide and unhide the rows ... but I seem to have not understood the concept for finding the cell correctly.

I get the error msg of wrong argument count or invalid assignment.

```
Sub hideAndSeek()
    Dim zellbereich As String

    For i = 7 To 43
        If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("project").Range.Cells(i, 2)) Then
            zellbereich = i & ":" & i
            Rows(zellbereich).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the proper way to refer to a worksheet cell (it will cause Run-time error):

```
Worksheets("project").Range.Cells(i, 2)
```

It should look like that:

```
Worksheets("project").Cells(i, 2)
```

---

Anyway, this task can be accomplished much easier. Here is the code to do that:

```
Sub hideAndSeek()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim rngEmpty As Excel.Range
    '------------------------------------------------------------

    With Worksheets("project")
        Set rng = Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(43, 2))
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End With

End Sub
```

I assumed that you want to check the range B7:B43 only, since this is what your original code suggests. If it is not true you can change this part:

```
        Set rng = Range(Cells(7, 2), Cells(43, 2))
```

for other range (note that `Cells(7, 2)` means column B and row 7 and not the opposite).

Comment: I assume that you meant "is _not_ the proper way" in your first sentence :-D

It works, thanks. And your code also works like a charm, the only problem is, that you delete the entire row. I just wanted to hide it. is there a special Hide command available?